# Algorithms for keeping number of backups constant

Tags: optimization, knapsack-problems

The problem is quite simple: backups are done at regular time intervals (with possible but rare exceptions). The storage however is not unlimited, and only a certain number of backups can be stored, latest ones being more valuable, and desired to be more frequent than old ones.

For example, there could be backups for each day for last two week, then once a week for the month, then once a month for three years, and the rest just once a year, the very first backup is to be saved however. Difference in backup sizes can be ignored. Before or after adding one more backup, one or more from old ones are to be selected for deletion (or further archiving).

It is actually not a problem to come up with ad hoc solution for this, but the question are:

- how this kind of a problem and algorithms for it's solution are called in computer science (or operation research and related disciplines)?
- what approaches are standard (may be, some notable solutions, named algorithms?) and what is the most efficient approach (time complexity-wise)?

It is clear, that this should be less complex than [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), but seems distantly related. If I am not mistaken, the problem is optimization one.

More specific problem definition:

For each step (when new backup is being added):

INPUT:

- $m > 2$ (number of backups)
- $\{t_i\}$ for $i \in M \subset \{1, \dots, n\},\qquad |M| \leq m$, $\qquad t_i \gt t_{i+1},\qquad t_i \in \mathbb N$ (times when backups were taken)
- function $f$, which specifies a frequency scale of remaining stored backup. For example, if $f$ is constant, it means that backups are maintained evenly. There may be some artificial exceptions for the first and last backup (it is probably stupid to drop the latest backup!).

OUTPUT: $t_j$ to be deleted. The remaining timestamps $M' = M \setminus \{t_j\}$ should remain distributed with increasing frequency. The exact function $f(t)$ for normalizing desired frequencies can be stepwise or of some other form. That is, interval lengths $t_{k-1} - t_k$ should increase with $t_k$.

The good solution (ideally - optimal) minimizes the residual (for example, mean square) - difference between desired remaining frequencies $f$ of backups and actual frequencies (eg, estimated by interpolation using moving window of 3 values).

I guess, there should be no big differences between different measures of error and ways to estimate error, because we have discrete values, but the function $f$ is what mostly defines the "shape" of the distribution. It could be a $e^t$, or a rough stepwise approximation.

(It is another question, what $f$ is of practical interest. But it is more complex, and one need to go into statistics on how old backups are really needed and how often, and probably into cost of storage vs cost of losses and such.)

Comment: Your question isn't precise enough; "What is the most efficient approach?" - what do you mean by "efficient", how do you compare two solutions? You're asking about the name of a "class of algorithms" but you haven't defined any algorithms at all.

Comment: I have defined the problem. So, presumably there are algorithms to solve the problem, and among them there are those with least time complexity. I have refined the question now.

Comment: Are you trying to arrange an actual backup scheme for actual data? If so, you should ask systems administrators, not computer scientists.

Comment: If you want to ask this question in the setting of computer science, then you need to define: (1) what the *input* to the problem is, (2) what consists a feasible *solution* and (3) how we *compare* two solutions to decide which is better.

Comment: I've formalized the input/output a little bit more.

Comment: As for the second part of the question, I will be probably able to google it if the first part will get right names.